# Ruby Gemfile & database adapters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am developing on an open source rails application and as a rails 3 project, it includes a Gemfile. The application is also dependent on a database adapter for active record. I can specify a specific adapter (like `gem 'sqlite3'`) within the Gemfile but this is not what I want to do. I advertise the app as beeing compatible with all the adapters active record is compatible with. Is there any way to specify that the app depends on a single database adapter  (out of a selection) but that one is sufficient? Something like

```
any_of do
  gem 'sqlite'
  gem 'mysql'
  etc.
end
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions how to approach the problem differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently installed something that generated an error, until I realized how they handled this.

```
group :postgresql do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :mysql do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

and then when you run bundler:

```
bundle install --without postgresql
```

Comment: I see, so this would then be integrated into the deployment process. That'll do, many thanks!

Comment: won't this change gemfile.lock though? depending on which db you choose? That's supposed to be checked in to the db also, so this might make that a problem.